# Using a segue from a UIViewController with UItextfield to populate a UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7, segue

Yes I am new to Xcode and coding in general. I did a bunch of research and figured out how to go from UItableviewcontroller to the viewcontroller then using the "unwind segue" to populate the table, which is not exactly what I want.

I would like the initial scene to be the viewcontroller rather than the table and as such the unwind segue isnt working. I've been trying to rearrange things for days but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ViewController.m

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.labelField.text.length > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[YYTData alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.labelField.text;
```

TableViewController.h

```
   @interface YYYTableViewController : UITableViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

Tableviewcontroller.m

```
   - (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    YYYFirstViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    YYTData *item = source.toDoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self loadInitialData];
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a segue strictly programmatically or are you using storyboard?

Comment: I'm using storyboard at the moment.

Comment: In order to give your viewController the ability to trigger segues, you'll have to set it to the `rootViewController:` of a navigationController in storyboard. I added an answer to this thread detailing how you can do this.

Comment: Your answer definitely helped thanks! But maybe I'm missing something very simple. So now that its embedded in a navigationcontroller, I have to send the data through a push segue or the `prepareforsegure:` rather than the my `(IBAction)unwindToList:` correct? This is where I think my main issue/sticking point is occuring.

I'm having trouble calling the code inside of the `unwindToList:` when moving it to an action on the viewcontroller

hope that makes sense

Comment: I would recommend passing the data to the next viewController with the prepareForSegue: method.

Comment: Okay cool. Last question, `[self.toDoItems addObject:item];` When carrying out the prepareForSegue: method, an error pops up, not found on object viewcontroller - the toDoItems is an array, declared in my tableviewcontroller.h, how do I get rid of the error?

Comment: Just to make sure that we're on the same page, you are adding objects to the toDoItems array in the `prepareForSegue:` method of your first viewController. Though these variables are not apart of viewController, simply adding `#import"yourTableViewController"` to viewController give you access to it. Just remember to declare the array in yourTableViewController.h after `@end`. A simple `NSMutableArray *toDoItems;` will do.

Comment: Now back to setting the value of toDoItems in `prepareForSegue:` (in viewController.m), you will not use `[self.toDoItems addObject:item];` but instead `[toDoItems addObject:item];`. Self will not work because toDoItems is not a part of the viewController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segues are used to navigate through viewControllers that are connected in a UINavigationController stack. To have viewControllers added to this stack, you have to first manually create segues in storyboard. You can access the viewControllers in your navigation stack with methods such as `performSegueWithIdentifier:`. In order to have your viewController be the first viewController in your navigation stack, do the following in storyboard:

1.) Delete all viewControllers that you have.

2.) Drag and drop a UINavigationController.

3.) Drag and drop a UIViewController (will be your first viewController and I will refer to it as viewController).

4.) Set the class of viewController to the class of your view controller.

--This is done by clicking on the viewController (in the left panel are of storyboard) and navigating to the identity inspector (in the right panel area of storyboard) and entering the name of the viewCotroller's class.

5.) Now you set the `rootViewController:` of navigationController to viewController by clicking on the navigationController (in the left panel area of storyboard), then looking in the connections inspector (last icon in the right panel of storyboard). Here you will see rootViewController, you'll right click from rootViewController and drag a line from it to your viewController (in the left panel of storyboard).

After completing these five steps, you can add a tableViewController in storyboard create a segue for it, and everything should work as you'd like it to.